# How can I delete game data on iPhone 5? I want to start it over

Tags: iphone, ios, games, game-center

I want to start Gardian Hunter from the start, but I can't delete my data.
Is it possible to delete it? Please help me.

I'm using an iPhone 5.

Answer (score 2):

You should just be able to delete the app and redownload it again, all game data should be deleted, then.

Comment: Are you sure - for some of my games all the data is in GamesCentre and deletion of the app (even a full iPhone reset to factory settings) did not remove the status - others do get all data removed (and I think the games cementer way is the way I would expect all good games to be)

Comment: When you go to delete it, it will ask you if you want to keep your Game Center data for the deleted game. Tap delete.

Answer (score 1):

App data is not stored in the app store only the game is. If game data is stored on the phone only then deleting the app, rebooting the phone, and downloading the app will clear it.

If the game data is stored on the game developer's server then you will have to ask the game developer how to clear it, or better create a new user ID for the game.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately this operation can not be done without removing the App on an non-jailbroken iDevice.

For  your safety, I suggest to remove the app as following: 
`Navigate to Settings => General => Usage => Manage Storage => Select the desired game/app => Delete App`

This will clear all cache info for the app and when you install it over, you may be able to start from scratch.

Beside that some games/apps store info onto their own servers and/or in the GameCenter.

For the games/apps that store the info onto their own servers you will not need to worry, but for the ones that store info in the GameCenter, you may need to look how to reset your score/info there.